# Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, react-test-renderer

I've been able to test ts files but as soon as I attempt to write a test for tsx files I get the error:

**const rendered = (0, _reactTestRenderer.create)();
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

Test File:

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "react-test-renderer";

describe("My Test", () => {
  test("My first test", () => {
    const rendered = create(<div />);

    console.log(rendered);
  });
});
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "13.3.0",
    "axios": "1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.1",
    "preval.macro": "5.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.6.4",
    "react-datepicker": "4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-window": "1.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "4.8.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "2.0.6",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-mock-axios": "^4.7.0-beta3",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
```

jestSetup.js

```
import { config } from "../src/shared/constants";

window.config = config;
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!axios)/"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  },
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: false,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/__mocks__/jestSetup.js"],
  watchman: true,
};
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
};
```

Comment: Show your `jestSetup.js`

Comment: Just added it. There's not much in it. It's just setting a bunch of constant variables on the global window object.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to babel.config.js to the array of presets:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ...,
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ...
  ],
};
```